# glMapBufferRange crashing on Android GLES app

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to morph some vertices on a GLES application on android and glMapBufferRange keeps crashing with the following error:

SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: address access protected (fault address: 0xef13d664))

I more or less followed the example of this web-site:

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html#update

but not sure if I am missing something.

I created my VBOs at initialization time and I can draw the object with no issues. The code of creation goes:

```
void SubObject3D::CreateVBO(VBOInfo &vboInfoIn) {
    // m_vboIds[0] - used to store vertex attribute data
    // m_vboIds[l] - used to store element indices
    glGenBuffers(2, vboInfoIn.vboIds);

    // Let the buffer all dynamic for morphing
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboInfoIn.vboIds[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 (GLsizeiptr) (vboInfoIn.vertexStride * vboInfoIn.verticesCount),
                 vboInfoIn.pVertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboInfoIn.vboIds[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 (GLsizeiptr) (sizeof(GLushort) * vboInfoIn.indicesCount),
                 vboInfoIn.pIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

struct VBOInfo {
    VBOInfo() {
        memset(this, 0x00, sizeof(VBOInfo));
        vboIds[0] = 0xdeadbeef;
        vboIds[1] = 0xdeadbeef;
    }

    // VertexBufferObject Ids
    GLuint vboIds[2];

    // Points to the source data
    GLfloat *pVertices;         // Pointer of original data
    GLuint verticesCount;
    GLushort *pIndices;         // Pointer of original data
    GLuint indicesCount;

    GLint vertexStride;
};
```

then later in the Rendering loop I tried to get the hold of my vertex pointer as such:

```
// I stored the information at creation time here:
VBOInfo mVBOGeometryInfo;
//later I call here to get the pointer
GLfloat *SubObject3D::MapVBO() {
    GLfloat *pVertices = nullptr;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBOGeometryInfo.vboIds[0]);

    GLsizeiptr length = (GLsizeiptr) (mVBOGeometryInfo.vertexStride *
                                      mVBOGeometryInfo.verticesCount);
    pVertices = (GLfloat *) glMapBufferRange(
            GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,
            length,
            GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT
    );

    if (pVertices == nullptr) {
        LOGE ("Could not map VBO");
    }
    return pVertices;
}
```

but it crashed right at glMapBufferRange.

This is an android application that uses NDK. The hardware is a Samsung S6 phone.

thx!

Comment: Did you create an ES 3.0 context? Can you successfully use other ES 3.x functionality?

Comment: Could you check that verticesCount, vertexStride and vboIds are the same when SubObject3D::CreateVBO is run as they are when SubObject3D::MapVBO runs?

Comment: @Columbo it is all correct as far as data. The vbo Ids, vertex size and stride are correct and valid. Plus if I don't call the map function I can render the object no problem. Am I missing something as far as code?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I can render the entire scene with everything no problem as long as I don't call the mapfunction.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. `glMapBufferRange()` is only available in ES 3.0 and later. Are you successfully using **3.0** features in the rest of your code?

Comment: @RetoKoradi as far I know, I think so. All headers include #include "<GLES3/gl3.h>". the code compile, links and runs fine. All shaders start with "#version 300 es". What would be the GLES 2.0 equivalent of glMapBufferRange()? I can try to convert that part of the code to 2.0 to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite painful to resolve this issue, but there is no problem with the code above per se. It was basically the include. My code was based off the google sample "more teapots" located here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/teapots

I had to follow their pattern and change my include to GLES from:

```
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
```

to use their stubs:

```
#include "gl3stub.h"
```

why? I don't know, but likely causing the linker to link incorrect code.